# BigQuery Extract string within JSON

Tags: json, google-bigquery, extract

How can I extract NPR from the string using REGEX_EXTRACT?

{'Id': None, 'Name': 'NPR'}

I've tried several methods but can't seem to find one that bigquery will accept. So far I have:

REGEX_EXTRACT(Source, )

Answer (score 0):

if your bigquery json column name is 'column1' you can extract it using below query
select column1.name from table
or
select column1['name'] from table

this will give you result you expecting.